# How to use nonce in CSP

Tags: node.js, content-security-policy

I've been reading the CSP documentation regarding using inline scripts with nonce (Number used only once), but I still don't get it fully.

- May I use the same nonce to different inline scripts? That is, may I do this?

HTTP layer:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-2726c7f26c'
```

Javascript inlined in HTML

```
<script nonce="2726c7f26c">
  var inline = 1;
</script>
<script nonce="2726c7f26c">
  var inline2 = 2;
</script>
```

- can you recommend me any node.js function to generate such nonces? Shall I use the `require('crypto')`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

My solution was correct

We create one `nonce` per HTTP request, we should not create one per script. So, my initial solution was correct. The CSP rules go into the HTTP layer, and thus one nonce per HTTP request.

Comment: Remarkable looking even now at a number of web pages explaining CSP nonces, and none of them make it clear that you can use one nonce for multiple scripts. Mozilla, Google, etc. fail to make it clear.  I totally misread it as requiring a new nonce for each script

Comment: I'm also looking for an explanation for nonce with multiple inline scripts. Thankfully, you posted this saves my time in proving this out.